# seeking prison fx and ambience libraries

Tags: ambience, library, fx

I'm on a feature that takes place exclusively in a prison. I have all the big libraries that have prison fx... I've had them forever and am feeling like I want something new.

Anyone got any good ideas on what's out there? I've been having trouble finding anything beyond individual FX from the likes of sound-dogs and whatnot. For what it's worth, it's a U.S., male prison. Thanks a lot!

Comment: and unfortunately, going to a prison and recording isn't doable due to schedule/budget constraints, otherwise that'd by all means be my go-to

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for mechanics, latches, doors, cells and the like (and not simply male prison walla), I had a lot of luck recently with a really reverberant park bathroom and doing a lot of door slams, locks, metal manipulation in there.

Slowing those down to half speed doubles the reverb time / sense of space and bulks up the sound of the mechanics as well. Definitely a viable replacement for the tired old jail libraries we've all got kicking around.

Let me know if you want me to send you over a few files, or give it a spin yourself!

Comment: Add to that, if you have access to Altiverb or similar, you could record just the ambiences, then you can use any dry effect with your custom ambience

Comment: that's a great idea, I can definitely see that working. Yeah, if you wouldn't mind sending some over, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Sure! Here they are, at normal speed and slowed down 200%.

https://mega.co.nz/#!B8ZEBbKD!Zua4E4dceQVY-YrwhbuzUhiQSw5LyWzKK4-XgGXRtDU

https://mega.co.nz/#!x4oxwTya!PMOH_WlK6EjF29Hwe7AQEITOPWWDB3D9-2ozkPbP9-k

Let me know when you've got them.